# Android resource linking failed '@colors/blue' is incompatible with attribute resource (attr) reference

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Android resource linking failed '@colors/blue' is incompatible with attribute resource (attr) reference.**

I'm trying to set a custom color to the firebase push notification icon. This is the portion of my config.xml that is giving me incompatibility error.

```
<platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <config-file parent="./application" target="AndroidManifest.xml" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/push" />
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@colors/blue" />
        </config-file>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/push-icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/push.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/push-icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/push.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/push-icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/push.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/push-icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/push.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/push-icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/push.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/colors.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/colors.xml" />
    </platform>
```

And this is the corresponding portion of my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@colors/blue" />
```

And the full route for the colors.xml file is:

> resources/android/xml/colors.xml

The target generated route is:

> app/src/main/res/xml/colors.xml

And finally the colors.xml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue">#38a8ff</color>
</resources>
```

**Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `color` without an `s`:

```
android:resource="@color/blue"
```

Comment: Well after changing the word to singular tense it no longer shows incompatibility erroe, but now it throws "error: resource color/blue (aka mx.com.finreal.clientes:color/blue) not found." Should I mark this as solved? it solved the error in question, regardless of now getting a new error.

Comment: U need to import the resource file to the Config xml